# How do I simulate throwing an exception at random point of code in Unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8851602/57428) about simulating throwing exceptions. Answers suggest I create a mock object that pretends being a real object.

That's not what I want to have. If I replace a real object I lose part of real code. I want to invoke real code with minimal changes and have an exception thrown from inside it at random point of that code.

Is it possible to have an exception thrown at random point of code being called from a Unit test?

Comment: Are you trying to test the exception handling?

Comment: What is the problem with losing part of real code when you test the error handling? You shouldn't test real code and error handling in the same test.

Comment: You could perhaps inject some code into the managed code generated by your object at a random point.

Comment: By mocking the code you guarantee that the exception is thrown the way you want in order to test the class. Are you confusing the class under test with the modules it uses?

Comment: @TwoMore: Yes, I want to be sure that exceptions other than of certain type are handled in specific way.

Comment: @adrianm: The real code could have swallowed an exception and so I'll have behavior different from when I use a dumb mock object. That's what I'd want to avoid.

Comment: _The real code could have swallowed an exception and so I'll have behavior different from when I use a dumb mock object_ - but you have tests for that class as well! it's not the ClassUnderTest's responsibility to make sure that other modules behave correctly

Comment: @sharptooth Can not you just simulate the situation in which such an exception is beeing thrown in the normal code? could you maby provide an example of such a case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't put randomness into your unit tests. it will only bring you troubles. a unit tests should always have some consistence. especially if you want him to tell you what went wrong when he went red. if you implement a random exception throwing into your unit tests it can happen that he SOMETIMES crashes and returns a red bar. maybe the next run it the error is gone again. this is really not what unit tests are here for and you will have big troubles finding the issue for that once-occurred failed test.

a much better approach is to systematically test critical parts of your code. replace each crucial method with a mocked object, which throws the type of exception you want to test for and cover each test case like this. this will give you much more information about what went wrong when you are looking for that error.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can think about this work around.

1- Make a function called RandomException(); that `throw` exception if a random value is divisible by 3 otherwise it won't throw the exception. make sure this function is encapsulcate in this block of code.

```
#if DEBUG
void RandomException()
{
    // gen random value
    // if random value % 3 == 0 throw the exception now
}
#else
void RandomException()
{
}
#endif
```

that way when you release the code these function calls won't affect the program.

I hope that idea helps you.

Comment: How do I make this function called from a random point of my code?

Comment: That's not how a TestProject works.. At least not where I work. Do you have test code shipped with your products?

Comment: @Default: No, we don't "ship" products, we run and maintain a web service, so customers never hold our code.

Comment: @sharptooth well, I still wouldn't add potential exceptionthrowing where I put my release code. I would put it in a separate test project.

Comment: @Default: Sure, I want that code being injected only when the test project is being run.

Comment: It is not possible and it is not applicable, for example x++; why this line would crash or throw exception !!!

Comment: You just call RandomException(); if you are sure these part would throw exception. If you care about your code try to increase the warning level to 4 and make sure you resolve all the warning you have got their

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to test the exception handling, i dont think this is a good approach to throw an exception randomly and check if it gets cought, if you need to test handling in certain conditions you need to simulate the condition in a real object, like an illegal situation which should cause an exception.

You still can produce this behaviour through a local varibale which you can set from outside (in your Unittest) which will cause the code to throw an exception depending on this variable, but as saied i dont think its a good approach.